# Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique. The following validation type was seen more than once: email

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, client-side-validation

I am getting this yellow screen of death. And I dont have any custom ModelValidatorProviders or DataAnnotationsExtensions or any such thing. Can any one suggest whats going wrong.
In the web.config when I change the following code to

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
```

things work fine. But I guess I loos client side validation by that. So can someone please guide me how to debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found NInject to be the culprit. I have then rebuilt the app with latest MVC5 and WebApi nuget packages and this sorted out the issue.

Comment: Thanks man. You save me from wasting my time. I had implemeted ninject with mvc and recently in same project implemented ninject for web api